# Celery tasks sharing underlying state

Tags: python, celery

I'd like to implement a scheduler for actions to be performed on a hardware resource in Python. The hardware resource is encapsulated in its own class, the object contains state information and therefore there should only ever be one instance of that object. I have tried to do this with [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes). My task base class is:

```
from celery import Task

class ObClTask(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def add(self, add_val):
        self.val += add_val
        return self.val

    def mult(self, mult_val):
        self.val *= mult_val
        return self.val
```

The Celery task definition is like this:

```
from celery import Celery
from obcl import ObClTask

@app.task(base=ObClTask)
def add(x):
    return add.add(x)

@app.task(base=ObClTask)
def mult(x):
    return mult.mult(x)
```

I start `celery` with `--concurrency=1` to ensure only one worker is spawned.

Then, running a sequence like

```
add.delay(5)
add.delay(5)
mult.delay(2)
mult.delay(2)
```

Will return `5`, `10`, `0`, `0` when what I'd like is `5`, `10`, `20`, `40` – i.e. `add` and `mult` operating on the same instance. I understand that `add` and `mult` generate different subclasses of `ObClTask`. But is there a way to achieve what I need with Celery?

*Edit:* This may work with a class property. But is this an antipattern?

Answer (score 1):

`@app.task(base=whatever)` creates a new task **class**, so you end up with two distinct task instances.

I'd stronly suggest you don't use task instances to persist state - this is ok for either read-only values or local caching (cf [the db connection cache in the fine manual](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation)) but not for this use case. If you want to maintain shared state between tasks executions, persist your state in some database, read it at the start of the task function and update it when done (and don't forget to setup some lock so only one single task can access this resource at a time).

Comment: Thanks – in my scenario, I only ever have one worker, so only one task should be accessing the resource at a given time anyways. If possible at all I'd like to avoid opening and closing the hardware resource – as reopening entails basically a hardware reset which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while looking for a solution to a similar problem. Here is what I ended up doing. I am using RabbitMQ as a broker and Redis as a results backend, but adapt it to your case:

File **obcl/obcl.py**:

```
class ObCl(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def add(self, add_val):
        self.val += add_val
        return self.val

    def mult(self, mult_val):
        self.val *= mult_val
        return self.val
```

File **obcl/obcl_tasks.py**:

```
from obcl.obcl import ObCl
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_shutting_down


app = Celery('obcl_tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost/')
my_obcl = ObCl()


@app.task
def add(x):
    return my_obcl.add(x)


@app.task
def mult(x):
    return my_obcl.mult(x)

@worker_shutting_down.connect
def task_sent_handler(sig=None, how=None, exitcode=None, **kwargs):
  # Maybe close hardware resources when shutting down the worker?
  # I had to in my case, you might too.
  pass
```

Running celery from the parent folder of the obcl module. Make sure to use `--concurrency=1` so you only have a single instance worker process controlling your hardware. :

```
celery -A obcl.obcl_tasks worker --pool=solo --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info

 -------------- celery@localhost v4.2.2 (windowlicker)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.18.0-16-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic 2019-03-24 17:10:03
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         obcl_tasks:0x7f443c0bc5c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . obcl.obcl_tasks.add
  . obcl.obcl_tasks.mult

[2019-03-24 17:10:03,041: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2019-03-24 17:10:03,049: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-03-24 17:10:04,070: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-03-24 17:10:04,086: INFO/MainProcess] celery@localhost ready.
```

Now you can call your tasks and should get your expected results.

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from obcl.obcl_tasks import add, mult
>>> test = add.delay(5)
>>> test.result
5
>>> test = add.delay(5)
>>> test.result
10
>>> test = mult.delay(2)
>>> test.result
20
>>> test = mult.delay(2)
>>> test.result
40
```